# Apply and remove a large CSS style section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to change the page style based on user preferences.

The page will load with a given style, but if the user clicks a button, the page layout should change. If he clicks again, the style should change back to the original style. The changes are large (about 70 CSS lines), but only change a *specific* part of the page.

I can write a JavaScript function that modifies the CSS styles for all the relevant tags, but that would be tedious and will introduce too much CSS into my code. I would rather keep it in the CSS file if I can.

I can also add styling `A` to the CSS file, with reference to class `A` in all the relevant tags and add style `B` to the CSS file, with reference to class `B` in all the relevant tags. Then the JavaScript code would just have to change the class on the relevant tags.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Toggle the class on the `body` (or a more relevant parent object) and then amend your CSS to be based on this class. This way all the UI is affected by only 1 line of JS code.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. please add it as an answer

Comment: Answer added for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you could toggle the class on the `body` (or a more relevant parent object) and then amend your CSS to be based on this class. This way all the UI is affected by only 1 line of JS code. For example:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('foobar');
});
```

```css
.example {
    background-color: red;
}

body.foobar .example {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, no script, just CSS, and very easy to implement and also very easy to have more than one layout to toggle between.

```css
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#toggle, #toggle2 {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked ~ label[for=toggle],
#toggle2:checked ~ label[for=toggle2] {
  background: #aaa;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .container {
  display: none;
}

#toggle2:checked ~ .container img:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle" class="toggle">
  Toggle
</label>
<input id="toggle2" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle2" class="toggle">
  Toggle 2
</label>

<div class="container">
  
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check something like this.And after click you can add/delete link to another css files.

```
var ss = document.createElement("link")
ss.type = "text/css"
ss.rel = "stylesheet"
ss.href = "style.css"
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ss);
```